# rake db:migrate not working properly without version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake

I have a simple rails app without dependencies (rails new example). Then I created a scaffold Student (rails g scaffold Student name:string). After, I run rake db:create and then rake db:migrate.

rake db:migrate returns nothing. It's not executing my migration, without no error on the screen. But, when I execute rake db:migrate VERSION=123456 the migration runs properly.

Do you have any idea what is happening with rake db:migrate without version? (I'm on MAC OS X)

thanks

Comment: Are there any new migrations to "migrate"?

Comment: Yes, there is one. I did the following steps: rails new my_app && rails g scaffold Student name:string && rake db:create && rake db:migrate

Comment: @user1985010- `VERSION=123456` doesn't make sense unless you have Student migration with this particular version number.

Comment: `rake db:migrate` executes nothing only when all the migrations are already run and `rake db:migrate VERSION= 123456` executes the migration with this version number.

Comment: Did you `cd new_app` after creating the Rails app? See your db/schema.rb file. What version number is shown there? Example: `ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130305185827)`. If everything else fails, do a `rm db/schema.rb` and migrate again.

Comment: @Saurabah, VERSION= 123456 was just an example.

Comment: @Leito, I have ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 0). I deleted that file and tried again. The file was created with the version 0.

Comment: What's your migration file name and contents?

Comment: what does your schema look like?

Comment: schema: ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 0) do; end;

migration:
cat db/migrate/20130307171742_create_students.rb 
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :students do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only logical answer I can come up is that your environment has the variable `VERSION` set with 0. Type this in the command line `echo $VERSION`

If you do, running `rake db:migrate` should be equivalent to `rake db:migrate VERSION=0` which would behave similarly to what you are describing. Unset the variable (`unset VERSION`) and try again.

If you don't, this answer is clearly incorrect.

Comment: Hi Leito,
That's the output:
echo $VERSION
0.0.1.3086

Comment: I don't know who's adding that, but try `unset VERSION` followed by `rake db:migrate`